# Weird problem with YouTube app on MIUI 10.2

Tags: youtube, miui-10

There is this problem with the YouTube app on MIUI 10.2. When I open the app, the 'YouTube' logo part at the top has completely disappeared and it just shows the search box, the notification bell, and the account picture.

Tried the usual things like rebooting the phone. No use. When I clear the app data or uninstall YouTube app updates and re-install them, it goes back to normal showing the logo, when, after that, I open the app for the first time. But when I close the app and open it later it goes back to no logo again. Tried everything except factory reset.

Any idea why this is happening? Some kind of weird virus thing or so? Not that I miss the YouTube logo terribly :-), but this glitch seems annoying and doesn't seem to go away despite my best efforts!

Comment: Did you try updating it? Bugs like this are generally fixed in the updates..

Comment: Yes I did. Tried uninstalling and re-installing. Cleared cache, cleared data. Works for just  one time after that. But the bug appears on subsequent times.

Comment: Could you mention the YouTube version, and possibly upload the screenshot when the issue happens? The YouTube app (v15.38.32) on my Nexus 5 (Android 7.1.2) shows a search icon instead, not a search box.

Comment: YouTube version 15.37.35. Also goes away when i manage to sign out of YouTube app.